Is there a way to backup existing tables without connecting to the Postgres server?
I will reset my computer, but I want to back up the relevant db's, but I cannot connect to the Postgres server via pgAdmin. When I look at the windows services section, it is stopped, but it cannot be started again, it gives an error. I also get an error when I try to connect using console. When I tried turning off the firewall settings, the situation did not change. Is there any way I can take a backup offline?

>psql -U postgres -W Password: psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

...but it cannot be started again, it gives an error. What is the error?

@AdrianKlaver "The service on the local computer started and stopped"

Then you need to look at Windows system logs to get more detail on what caused  ...started and stopped.

you can  do a File system backup
see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-file.html

An alternative backup strategy is to directly copy the files that PostgreSQL uses to store the data in the database; Section 19.2 explains where these files are located. You can use whatever method you prefer for doing file system backup

but there are restrictions#
like

The database server must be shut down in order to get a usable backup.

And also

If you have dug into the details of the file system layout of the database, you might be tempted to try to back up or restore only certain individual tables or databases from their respective files or directories. This will not work

If you try this, you must have the same major version installed. That is not said explicitly in the prior paragraph, but the structure can be changed from version to version.
And you can find more possibility's, but there are also restrictions, that have to be observed.
conclusion
a "normal" backup, is the easiest way to get a clean back up, but for that the server has to run as you noticed

There is no guarantee that a file backup can be restored to a database that actually works.

if the server is stopped, you can copy all files and put them in another postgres instance, it will start with the database, i  believe that there cold be3 complications, for example when you change the version, so if a "normal" backup is nt possible, because of a system, crash , it will work

I think that the answer is good. You may want to mention that you need to start the server with the same PostgreSQL major version on the data directory to get access.
